# how to solve this set of integro-differential equations analytically?

Tags: integration

I'm stuck with the following system of integro-differential equations and I need to know if it can be analytically solved or not.
$$\dot{f}(x)+ a_1 f(x) + a_2\int_{x_0}^x k(x,y) f(y) dy+a_3= b_1 g(x)+b_2 \int_{x_0}^x k(x,y) g(y) dy $$
$$\dot{g}(x)+ c_1 g(x) +c_2 \int_{x_0}^x k(x,y) g(y) dy+c_3= d_1 f(x)+ d_2\int_{x_0}^x k(x,y) f(y) dy$$
Excluding $f$ and $g$, all function and coefficients are known.

Please let me know if you have any idea for solving this or any clue to better search for the answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Which equations?

Comment: Thank you. The two coupled integro-differential equations that I have added to the question.